# Trouble: fwrite a 2D array to a .txt file

Tags: arrays, file, pointers, fwrite

I must be making a simple mistake somewhere...I'm new to c++ and coding in general. I want to write/initialize a 2D array to a .txt file, depending on the dimensions chosen by the user. This is the "Game of Fifteen" assignment for CS50.io
I'm also printing the board in the terminal just to make sure it looks right...(I realize it's not necessary yet in the program)...
THANK YOU

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

FILE *board1 = fopen("board1.txt", "w");
printf("ENTER SIZE OF BOARD 3-9\n");

int d = get_int();
int D = d * d;
int arr[d][d];
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            {
                D -= 1;
                arr[i][j] = D;
                printf("%2i ", D);


            }
            printf("\n");
        }
fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr), d*d, board1);
fclose(board1);
}
```

Comment: Please specify what does not work, what it should do and what happens instead. Please note, that fwrite will write the array as binary data, probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you--you're right--I want to write the array as a string of integers to the txt file. Would I use fprintf instead?

Comment: Then try writing to the file with fprintf inside the for loop